# Reorder column by a specific cell keys

Tags: excel

I have this problem:
[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img843/6652/oese.jpg]

*Every text inside cells in column B are the keys*.
 But, for example, **B3** is present in *E5* and **B4** is in *D6*.
I want to align column C, D, E, F, G, H, I, L etc so:
[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img819/9691/d85g.jpg]

As you can see column A - B remain at the same position but cell of column C, D, E, F, G, H, I, L etc are aligned based on the key of column B. 
For example `narod.ru/disk/39013001..` that was previously on line 5 now is on the same line on column B. This because they have same value.
 `http://rusfolder.com/223857` has a different text to `http://www.ifolder.ru/223857` but for the specific hoster I want to consider how the same value or that `http://rusfolder.com/` or `http://rusfolder.ru/`  = `http://www.ifolder.ru/` in fact after hoster name I have the same number `223857`.
But as you can see other text cells on column C, D, E, F, G etc, which have different values from column B, move according to the same key.
 For example `http://ifolder.ru/82135` ***is not a key*** but is near the key `narod.ru/disk/39013001..`. 
I want consider from column C to column Z like a single row block. If inside a row block I have a key (always refers to cell on column B) like `narod.ru/disk/39013001..` then that row block moves on the same row of column B that have the same key(s)

**summary**: is a KEY if text are same or before same number I have `rusfolder.com/.ru`
 *is not a key for other text cells because on cells of column B this values are not present.*
If I have 2 or more keys on the same row block is always the rule before.

**What formula should I use to have this alignment in Excel?**

Comment: Will the 'key' (for example, 223857), always be a number or could it be a text string? Also, will the keys always be the same depth at the host (e.g. if key A is after the 4th '/' will the matching key be after the 4th '/' in a different URL?)

Also, will the numeric/alphanumeric keys be totally unique?

Comment: it could be also a text string. For hoster like *ifolder.ru* or *rusfolder.com* or *rusfolder.ru* is always a number. For *depositfiles* i want consider the key A after the last or second-last **/**. For other links keys must are totally unique or at least equal 7-8 digit alphanumeric. Thanks for question

Comment: Would you be willing to say that all of your keys are within the first 10 '/' characters? First 20?

Comment: Also, how many values are we talking about? 100? 1000? 10000? Is the list growing?

Comment: For ifolder, rusfolder, after **last** `/` within 10 characters. Example: `http://rusfolder.com/38574185`.If after `/38574185` is unique or within 7-8 characters it could be considerating a key. For depositfiles **after the last** `/` within 8 characters. Depositfiles example: `http://dfiles.eu/de/files/ndr7uwp9m`. If after, only for depositfiles, `/ndr7uwp9m` is unique or within 8-9 characters it could be considerating a key.The other links must be equal to the key. if the links are exactly the same they can be considered as keys. We are talking about 100 values ​​at a time.

Comment: And can you guarantee they will all start with http://?

Comment: yes, all start with http://

Comment: Are you hoping to do this all with formulas or are you planning on using Visual Basic code?

Comment: I'm okay if you're using Visual Basic code

Comment: can u help me StephenH?